# Slick Postgres: How to search in a list of strings using the like operator

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick

There is a simple database entity:

```
case class Foo(id: Option[UUID], keywords: Seq[String])
```

I want to implement a search function which returns all entities of type `Foo` which have at least one keyword that contains the search string.

I'm using Slick and tried this:

```
def searchKeywords(txt: String): Future[Seq[Foo]] = {
  val action = Foos.filter(p => p.keywords.any like s"%$txt%").result
  db.run(action)
}
```

This piece of code compiles, but when executing, I get this SQL error:

`PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "any"`

The generated sql statement looks like:

`select "id", "title", "tagline", "logo", "short_desc", "keywords", "initial_condition", "work_process", "end_result", "ts", "lm", "v" from "projects" where any("keywords") like '%foo%'`

And it does not work with postgresql. (I'm using v12)

Schema for the table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foos
(
    id                  UUID            NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    keywords            varchar[]       NOT NULL
);
```

How can I achieve to search in a list of strings using the `like` operator?

Answer (score 0):

From a pure SQL point of view, you need a derived table to achieve that. I hope some expert corrects me if I'm wrong but you can't use SQL operator like on a array.

Supposing your table construction is :

```
CREATE TABLE foos
(
    id                  UUID            NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    keywords            varchar[]       NOT NULL
);
```

Then an SQL way of retrieving the results would be :

```
select * from (
  select id, unnest(keywords) as keyw from foos
  ) myTable where keyw like '%foo%'
```

Otherwise, the syntax you're using for the `like` operator seems correct.

```
myProperty like s"%$myVariable"
```

Comment: The code compiles. It does not compile without `.any`. I did not implement some postfix any method. `.any` comes with slickpg. I tried with `List[String]` with same result.

Comment: can you print the sql query that is generated please ? you can use `.statements` to get the generated query

Comment: please have a look. I updated my post with the generated sql.

Comment: can you print the schema of your table as well please ?

Comment: sql schema added to the post.

Comment: It seems like you need a derived table to unnest your array. I updated the answer with the correct SQL way of doing it. I still need to test the Scala slick way before sharing it